# Google App Invites only sometimes sending SMS

Tags: android, api, google-app-invites

So I'm currently trying to test out Google App Invites API, I'm able to send emails, but SMS messages only go through sometimes. I'm currently using a release build variant and using a release-key for the google json file. I've looked at the other StackOverflow questions about these SMS messages not sending but I've made sure my message is the correct length and no special characters are involved, can anyone tell me if there is a cooldown for sending invites through this API or why SMS messages only go through sometimes?